# perform a task in parellel

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have to read from a queue(receive queue) and perform result=DoWork(received msg) and then send the result to another queue(send queue). The messages keep coming in the receive queue. I want to do this in parellel means since each received msg is independent from the old received or sent message,i want many threads to do the task in parellel. What is the way to do it in C#. Also the receive Queue and the send Queue is fixed for all threads. How to lock them ???

Comment: By reviewing your question I think you should use MSMQ WCF service. You can have many online examples for the same to have glimpse on MSMQ services.

Comment: No queueing is fine. I know how to put into and read from a queue. Right now I have single thread which performs "read, compute write". I want many threads to do this simultaneously.